# Swift 3.0 Search Bar Filters by letters (not words)

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uisearchbar

I want my search bar to filter a tableView by non-case sensitive letters. Currently, I have it set so that it filters by case sensitive words and I am not sure how to populate the tableView by letters used in the search bar.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if newMessageSearchBar.text == nil || newMessageSearchBar.text == "" {

        isSearching = false

        view.endEditing(true)

        messagesTableView.reloadData()

    } else {

        isSearching = true

        nameList = sortedUserNames.filter({$0 == searchBar.text})

        messagesTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

My dataSource is sortedUserNames, and I set it to nameList. I am not sure if the tableView is refreshed only when a word is completed or if the filter function does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of equal comparing, which is only return true on full equal, use `contains` instead, lowercase make it non-case sensitive

```
nameList = sortedUserNames.filter({$0.lowercased().contains(searchBar.text.lowercased())})
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it actually works for me. When you try to search for a capital later and for a lowercase the words whit that specific letter will appear.

```
  func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if searchWordsBar.text == nil || searchWordsBar.text == "" {

        isSearching = false
        view.endEditing(true)
        originalWordsTableView.reloadData()

    } else {
        isSearching = true
        filteredWords = originalWords.filter { originalWords in return originalWords.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
    }
         originalWordsTableView.reloadData()

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the choice of yours how you want to do the search, if you want the table to contain the exact search string provided then "==" will serve you the best, but if you want that the name may contain any characters/substring of search string then "contains" will be your choice.

```
nameList = sortedUserNames.filter({$0.lowercaseString == searchBar.text.lowercaseString})
```